# Regular Expressions with lookahead in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.9.2, regex-lookarounds

My current regex battle is replacing all commas before a number in a string. The regex must then ignore all following commas.  I've been screwing around on rubular for about an hour and can't quite seem to get something working.

Test String...

```
'this is, a , sentence33 Here, is another.'
```

Desired Output...

```
'this is comma a comma sentence33 Here, is another.'
```

So something along the lines of...

```
testString.gsub(/\,*\d\d/,"comma")
```

To give you some background, I'm doing a little scraping sideproject.  The elements I'm gathering are largely comma separated beginning with a two digit age.  However sometimes theres a headline preceeding the age that may contain commas. To preserve the structure I set up later on, I need to replace the commas in the headline.

AFTER TRYING STACK OVERFLOW'S ANSWER...

I'm still having some issues.  Don't laugh but here's the actual line from the screen scraping thats causing problems...

```
statsString =     "              23,  5'9\",  140lb,  29w,                        Slim,                 Brown       Hair,             Shaved Body,              White,    Looking for       Friendship,    1-on-1 Sex,    Relationship.   Out      Yes,SmokeNo,DrinkNo,DrugsNo,ZodiacCancer.      Versatile,                  7.5\"                    Cut, Safe Sex Only,     HIV      Negative, Prefer meeting at:Public Place.                   PerformerContact  xxxxxx87                                                   This user has TURNED OFF his IM                                     Send Smile      Write xxxxxx87 a message:"
```

First to all of these fragments I add 'xx, ' so that my comma filtering will work in all cases, those with and without text ahead of the age. Followed by the actual fix.  The output is below...

```
statsString = 'xx, ' + statsString

statsString = statsString.gsub(/\,(?=.*\d)/, 'comma');

 => "xxcomma               23comma  5'9\"comma  140lbcomma  29wcomma                        Slimcomma                 Brown       Haircomma             Shaved Bodycomma              Whitecomma    Looking for       Friendshipcomma    1-on-1 Sexcomma    Relationship.   Out      YescommaSmokeNocommaDrinkNocommaDrugsNocommaZodiacCancer.      Versatilecomma                  7.5\"                    Cutcomma Safe Sex Onlycomma     HIV      Negativecomma Prefer meeting at:Public Place.                   PerformerContact  xxxxx87                                                   This user has TURNED OFF his IM                                     Send Smile      Write xxxxxxx87 a message:"
```

Comment: Why isn't the comma after `Here` replaced? Because `Here` starts with a capital letter? You need to provide a little more detail about your requirements. And perhaps a few more examples of input and desired output. You say 'replacing commas before a number', but that's not what your example is doing.

Comment: Doing this in a single regexp seems doomed for failure; is this a homework problem that must be solved this way or are you simply trying to solve the problem and got stuck thinking that regexp was the best way to solve it?

Comment: Just added some background info in the question.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @alan - Because there is no digit/number after that comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Code:***

```
testString = 'this is, a , sentence33 Here, is another.';
result = testString.gsub(/\,(?=.*\d)/, 'comma');
print result;
```

***Output:***

`this iscomma a comma sentence33 Here, is another.`

***Test:***

http://ideone.com/9nt1b

Comment: If you are sure that number is (at least) 2 digits, then you can replace `\d` with `\d\d` on the regex. But with `\d` it will do what you are asking in the question, regardless of how many digits such number has.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That did the trick.  The only issue now is some conditional logic.  When the headline that precedes the two digits isn't present the regex garbles all the commas I need downsetram.  I might try testString.gsub(/^\,(?=.*\d)/, 'comma'); or something similar

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you please post a new question for that and drop comment here with the link to that question? Please provide as much details as can to understand your issue.

Comment: Actually this code isn't helping as much as I initially thought it was.  When I run the lines above in irb they do produce the indicated output, however in my script they turn all the ,'s into 'comma'. I'm adding the code above

Comment: @user1306973 - Because there is always some number somewhere (even far) after such comma. If that is not what you want, then your question is incorrect, as my answer is the code that is solution for what you are asking for...

Answer (score 1):

Not so short, but, seems to solve your task:

```
str = 'this is, a , sentence33 Here, is another.'

str = str.match(/(.*)(\d+.*)/) do

    before = $1
    tail = $2

    before.gsub( /,/, 'comma' ) + tail
end

print str
```

Comment: To check if *something* is following the match you need to use `(?=X)`, where `X` is what should follow the match - so in this case it is anything or nothing `.*` with digit `\d`, so then `(?=.*\d)`, Welcome to Stackoverflow.