# Overlapping string matching using regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

Imagine we have some sequence of letters in the form of a string, call it

```
str = "gcggcataa"
```

The regular expression

```
r = /(...)/
```

matches any three characters, and when I execute the code

```
str.scan(r)
```

I get the following output:

```
["gcg", "gca", "taa"]
```

However, what if I wanted to scan through and instead of the distinct, non-overlapping strings as above but instead wanted to get this output:

```
["gcg", "cgg", "ggc", "gca", "cat", "ata", "taa"]
```

What regular expression would allow this?

I know I could do this with a loop but I don't want to do that

Comment: If you realize that something is unrelated, then do not put that in the question. It is extra burden for the reader of this question. And this is a programming site, not a biology site.

Comment: Not sure if Ruby supports Lookaheads, but then /(?=(...))./ should work (this syntax work in .NET and judging by other SO posts it should work in Ruby as well) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237474/regular-expressions-with-lookahead-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "gcggcataa"
str.chars.each_cons(3).map(&:join) # => ["gcg", "cgg", "ggc", "gca", "cat", "ata", "taa"]
```